# Error launching application after ClickOnce deployment- An application for this deployment is already installed with a different application identity

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce

As part of my continuous integration build the application is deployed as a ClickOnce application. This works great the first time, but when I try the launch the app after an update has been deployed I get the following error.

> An application for this deployment is
>   already installed with a different
>   application identity.

If I run `mage.exe -cc` to clear the application cache for all ClickOnce apps then I can launch the application just fine.

Has anyone run into this before? How can I fix this?

Here are the steps in my build script that publish the ClickOnce application.

```
./tools/windows_sdk/mage.exe
    -New Application
    -Processor msil
    -ToFile "C:\temp\build\RoadrunnerTrap.exe.manifest"
    -Name "Roadrunner Trap"
    -Version 1.0.0.1
    -FromDirectory "C:\temp\build"

# artifacts from C:\temp\build\ are copied to \\server\publish\v1.0.0.1\

./tools/windows_sdk/mage.exe
    -New Deployment
    -Processor msil
    -Install false
    -Publisher "Acme, Inc."
    -ProviderUrl "\\server\publish\RoadrunnerTrap.application"
    -Name "Roadrunner Trap"
    -AppManifest "\\server\publish\v1.0.0.1\RoadrunnerTrap.exe.manifest"
    -ToFile "\\server\publish\RoadrunnerTrap.application"
```

Note that the version number does change with every deployment.

Comment: How does it change? (the version number)?

Comment: The build script increments the version number.